# PHP trouble with single and double quotes + array

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, href

the part with the a href won't work

```html
<?php
    $key=$_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "neukenet");
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from blog_content where caption LIKE '%{$key}%'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
      $array[] = <a href="#">$row['caption']</a>;
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: Instead of adding single quote I suggest add anchor when u use loop for this array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to echo the variable(**concatenate**) from the while loop and then need to save into the `array()` variable. Without **concatenate** your data will not be printed into it.

> You have not closed the PHP tag so that you need to use `'` operator to concatenate based on the forward quotes that you have used or else your `<a>` tag will be throwing out error over to the solution. And your `json_encode()` will also replicate the same.

**Replace:**

```
$array[] = <a href="#">$row['caption']</a>;
```

**With:**

```
$array[] = '<a href="#">'.$row['caption'].'</a>';
```

Rather than that all the other code looks fine and the entire code will look like as follows.

```
<?php
    $key=$_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "neukenet");
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from blog_content where caption LIKE '%{$key}%'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
      $array[] = '<a href="#">'.$row['caption'].'</a>';
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to store the anchor tags within quotes and use concatenate operator.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $array[] = '<a href="#">' . $row['caption']. '</a>'; // Modify this line
}
echo json_encode($array);
```